# OpenGL with SDL2 doesn't return the right version

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glew, sdl-2

I have an SDL2 application in which I want to create an OpenGL 3.2 context. I googled a bit and started following this tutorial: http://open.gl/context#SDL

Everything seems to work except for the last step. When I had to implement this piece of code:

```
GLuint vertexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);

printf("%u\n", vertexBuffer);
```

My application doesn't seem to have a reference to the functor that should be there. I know there are some people here who had the same problem but I didn't find a solution there. When I output the GL_VERSION it says it's 1.1.0 although I say it should be 3.2.0. Here's my code:

```
// START SDL
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
{
    logSDLError(std::cout, "SDL_Init");
    return 1;
}

// SETUP OPENGL SETTINGS
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);

// OPENING WINDOW
m_pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL/OpenGL Game Client - With Networking Library", 100, 100, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
if (m_pWindow == nullptr)
{
    logSDLError(std::cout, "CreateWindow");
    return 2;
}

// CREATE AN OPENGL CONTEXT ASSOCIATED WITH THE WINDOW.
m_GlContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_pWindow);
if( m_GlContext == NULL )
{
    printf( "OpenGL context could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
}

//Initialize GLEW
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; 
GLenum glewError = glewInit();
if( glewError != GLEW_OK )
{
    printf( "Error initializing GLEW! %s\n", glewGetErrorString( glewError ) );
}

printf((char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION));
```

I have a FirePro graphics card that should be able to run OpenGL 4.0. I checked my driver updates and everything should be fine + I get no compile warnings saying that something might be wrong with OpenGL or Glew or SDL.

One thing I had to do to make glGetString() working was to include GL\freeglut.h. I don't really know why that is because it doesn't say so in the tutorial I followed.

Comment: What platform are you running this on? And what driver? The version 1.1.0 suggests to me that you run this on windows and somehow got microsoft's opengl renderer instead of the one from AMD.

Comment: I'm running Windows 8.1, I downloaded the AMD driver from the HP support website for my laptop. I tried a program called OpenGl Extension Viewer a minute ago and it days I'm running 1.1.0 so it might not be the code

Comment: Not sure if this will help but check if your card/laptop is listed [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) when you choose Step 1: Notebook Graphics, Step 2: Mobility FirePro Series, it might be a newer driver (you should probably fully uninstall previous driver before installing this one). That said, even if the driver is outdated it would still be pretty weird to only give you ancient OpenGL 1.1 instead of at least something like 1.5/2.x... Which might suggest that Windows is not actually using it and you are running on some kind of default fallback driver.

Comment: Maybe your laptop use integrated video card for you program (for example Intel). And this integrated video card supports only 1.1 version.

Comment: it's not listed. I have to go to the HP website do download the driver. Unick: So how would I enable my hardware to be used via my Visual Studio built application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I forgot to mention that I'm using MSTSC to remote from my desktop to my laptop (which is easier to work) and apparently this changes the graphics device.

I tried opening my application from the actual laptop and suddenly it worked, giving the right OpenGL version and everything.

Stupid mistake, I should've found this earlier.